# Razor Controller value is null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

The controller value is null but in the view I see it being sent in the debugger?
Is there something that I am missing?

View

```
    <div id="guidelineName">
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "GuidelinesPicklist", new { GuidelineId = Model.GuidelineId,leaveOutAlgorithmItems = true,separateActiveItems = true}); }
    </div>
```

Debugger
Id is seen
[image: Id is seen]

Controller value is null
[image]

```
public ActionResult Index(string value, bool leaveOutAlgorithmItems = false, bool separateActiveItems = false, bool clientOnly = false)
        {
            string x = value;
            return Widget(value, new PicklistSettingsModel
            {
                Placeholder = "Choose a guideline...",
                ClientOnly = clientOnly,
                AdditionalArguments =leaveOutAlgorithmItems || separateActiveItems
                    ? new object[]
                      {
                          value,
                          leaveOutAlgorithmItems,
                          separateActiveItems
                      }
                    : null
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed string value to GuidelineId